# How do I install glib?

Tags: empathy, compiling

I want to build the Empathy in Ubuntu 11.04.
When I follow the build process,

```
 ./autogen.sh
```

The shell said to me that

```
libtoolize: copying file `m4/lt~obsolete.m4'
checking for autoconf >= 2.53...
testing autoconf2.50... not found.
testing autoconf... found 2.67
checking for automake >= 1.9...
testing automake-1.11... found 1.11.1
checking for libtool >= 1.5...
testing libtoolize... found 2.2.6b
checking for glib-gettext >= 2.2.0...
testing glib-gettextize... not found.
***Error***: You must have glib-gettext >= 2.2.0 installed
to build Empathy.  Download the appropriate package for
from your distribution or get the source tarball at
ftp://ftp.gtk.org/pub/gtk/v2.2/glib-2.2.0.tar.gz
```

But when I cannot find the way to install glib. What should I do
to install that in ubuntu 11?

Comment: Why do you ask for `gnome-common` that is not even mentioned in that output?

Comment: @enzotib I revised the title to match what is really being asked.

Answer (score 118):

You need **libglib2.0-dev** for glib-gettext. You can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev
```

Comment: I'm allergic to `apt-get` :). So, I used `sudo apt install libglib2.0-dev` instead.

Comment: apt-get is the older "outdated" version

Answer (score 13):

you also need to install libgtk2.0-dev in order to install glib completely (glib is a part of : libgtk2.0-dev)

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
```

see this link for more explaination: 
[installing gtk and glib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275196/installing-gtk-and-glib)

Comment: This one solved my problem. I installed `libglib2.0-dev` before but was encountering problems installing `gobject-introspection`. Tried to install glib manually but didn't help.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you search for available ppa's if you want to just checkout the newer empathy than you have. I think this [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~telepathy/+archive/ppa) is the best bet Or just do this

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:telepathy/ppa`

Or if you need to build it.

`sudo apt-get build-dep empathy`

which will install all the dependencies required to build empathy from source.

Comment: Need to say that `build-dep` will install al required dependencies for building the repo version of empathy. The newer version could require other packages too, or newer versions of some package.

Comment: @sagarchalise when I use the second command to build, shell said .Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Build-Depends dependency for empathy cannot be satisfied because no available versions of package libnotify-dev can satisfy version requirements