# Empathy stop working

Tags: empathy

Im getting a little problem with empathy.

It suddenly stoped work, and im getting and error. I've sented the report, but till now, there's no resolution.

My system is updated. Im using Ubuntu 12.04.

The error says: Sorry, Ubuntu presented an internal error

I can't copy the stracktrace but it says something about libglib and other things..

Is anyone experimenting this kind of problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling libglib. Here is a link to an AskUbuntu forum on it. [How do I install glib?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58321/how-do-i-install-glib)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are facing the following issue:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/empathy/+bug/997017

If you facing above bug, then you are out of luck. People suggest to remove all the libraries of Empathy and re-install to check if it works. I have not tested so can't guarantee if it will work or not.

Comment: It's the same problem :(

Comment: I replaced empathy with pidgin just because of this issue. It's shame that default IM client does not work. God knows when we will get a decent IM client like Trillian for Linux